# SIPSorcery slow parsing times

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to replace a custom parser for sip messages with SIP Sorcery

Here is an example invite message

```
INVITE sip:1112223333@1.1.1.1:5060;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 5.5.5.5:5080;branch=z9hG4bKFQamuarZ;rport
From: <sip:2223332233@1.1.1.1>;tag=542A74E5-64AD7CDB00025F8D-5BA54700
To: <sip:1112223333@1.1.1.1>
CSeq: 10 INVITE
Call-ID: adsadsaseasaasdasadsawsd
Route: <sip:2.2.2.2:5060;received=sip:1.1.1.1:5060%3blr%3btransport%3dudp;lr>
Max-Forwards: 70
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces
Content-Type: application/sdp
Contact: <sip:5.5.5.5:5080;transport=udp>
Content-Length: 322
```

If I then pass that through these methods

```
public static SIPMethodsEnum GetSipMethod(string sipMessage)
{
    return SIPRequest.ParseSIPRequest(sipMessage).Method;
}

public static SIPHeader GetSipHeaders(string sipMessage)
{
    var mess = SIPMessageBuffer.ParseSIPMessage(sipMessage, null, null);

    return SIPHeader.ParseSIPHeaders(mess.SIPHeaders);
}
```

They can take anywhere from 26ms-100ms+

For reference I have a little custom bit of code that was handling the functionality of `GetSipMethod` and it runs in <1ms

```csharp
string[] message = _invite.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

string firstLine = message[0].Trim();
string[] firstLineParts = firstLine.Split(' ');

if (firstLineParts.Length < 2) return;

string sipMethod = firstLineParts[0];

switch (sipMethod)
{
    case "INVITE":
        HandleInvite(hepPacket);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

My hope is that I am using the sipsorcery library wrong and that there is a much faster way to achieve the same results.

I did some further testing using the sipsorcery package with BenchmarkDotNet

Here are the benchmark test

```csharp
private string _invite = "INVITE sip:1112223333@1.1.1.1:5060;transport=udp SIP/2.0\r\nVia: SIP/2.0/UDP 5.5.5.5:5080;branch=z9hG4bKFQamuarZ;rport\r\nFrom: <sip:2223332233@1.1.1.1>;tag=542A74E5-64AD7CDB00025F8D-5BA54700\r\nTo: <sip:1112223333@1.1.1.1>\r\nCSeq: 10 INVITE\r\nCall-ID: adsadsaseasaasdasadsawsd\r\nRoute: <sip:2.2.2.2:5060;received=sip:1.1.1.1:5060%3blr%3btransport%3dudp;lr>\r\nMax-Forwards: 70\r\nAllow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, MESSAGE\r\nSupported: replaces\r\nContent-Type: application/sdp\r\nContact: <sip:5.5.5.5:5080;transport=udp>\r\nContent-Length: 322";

[Benchmark]
public SIPMessageBuffer TestSipMessageBuffer()
{
    return SIPMessageBuffer.ParseSIPMessage(_invite, null, null);
}

[Benchmark]
public SIPRequest TestSipRequest()
{
    return SIPRequest.ParseSIPRequest(_invite);
}

[Benchmark]
public SIPHeader TestSipHeader()
{
    SIPRequest sipReq = SIPRequest.ParseSIPRequest(_invite);
    return sipReq.Header;
}
```

```
|               Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Allocated |
|--------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|----------:|
| TestSipMessageBuffer | 26.24 us | 0.397 us | 0.372 us |   4.74 KB |
|       TestSipRequest | 42.77 us | 0.427 us | 0.400 us |  26.12 KB |
|        TestSipHeader | 42.84 us | 0.496 us | 0.440 us |  26.12 KB |
```

This is quite different from what I previously reported(should have done proper performance testing on my side)

Still though I ended up building a simple class for my use case below

```
private static readonly Regex CallIdRegex = new Regex("(Call-ID|i): (.+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static readonly Regex ToURIRegex = new Regex("(To|t): *<sip:(.*?)@", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static readonly Regex FromURIRegex = new Regex("(From|f):.*<sip:(.*?)@", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static SIPMethodsEnum GetSipMethod(string sipMessage)
{
    string firstLine = GetFirstLine(sipMessage);

    string[] firstLineParts = firstLine.Split(' ');

    string sipMethod = firstLineParts[0];

    if(Enum.TryParse(sipMethod, true, out SIPMethodsEnum method))
    {
        return method;
    }

    return SIPMethodsEnum.UNKNOWN;
}

public static string GetFirstLine(string sipMessage)
{
    return sipMessage.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, 2)[0].Trim();
}

public static string GetCallId(string sipMessage)
{
    var match = CallIdRegex.Match(sipMessage);

    return (match.Success) ? match.Groups[2].Value.Trim() : "";
}

public static string GetToURIUser(string sipMessage)
{
    var match = ToURIRegex.Match(sipMessage);

    return (match.Success) ? match.Groups[2].Value.Trim() : "";
}

public static string GetFromURIUser(string sipMessage)
{
    var match = FromURIRegex.Match(sipMessage);

    return (match.Success) ? match.Groups[2].Value.Trim() : "";
}
```

This method was actually faster then my original

```
|       Method |       Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Allocated |
|------------- |-----------:|---------:|---------:|----------:|
| TestPrevious | 3,084.3 ns | 20.50 ns | 18.17 ns |    2.3 KB |
|      TestNew |   929.0 ns |  9.56 ns |  7.99 ns |   1.76 KB |
```

So in my production enviroment using my custom code the CPU is hovering around  20-30% usage

If I use the Sipsorcery package to do the same the cpu hits 80%

Using the sipsorcery package is in reference 46 times slower then what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

SIP Sorcery is a robust tool that efficiently handles parsing for you, saving significant time in development. The advantage here is that it allows you to leverage the work that's already been done, rather than reinventing the wheel.

When building software, it's easy to fall into the trap of premature optimization. This often leads to unnecessary complexity and longer development time. Utilizing tools like SIP Sorcery can mitigate these issues, accelerating the development process.

Regarding performance, the pertinent question to ask is: "Is it fast enough for my use case?" In my experience, using SIP Sorcery, I've been able to comfortably process 6-8k messages per second on a machine with 4 low-end CPU cores (Intel 2.0 Ghz Silver). It's worth noting that the limiting factor here is often not the parsing speed, but the network stack traffic capacity.

Hence, I'd recommend considering SIP Sorcery for your project, provided it meets your speed and performance requirements. It offers a good balance between development efficiency and runtime performance.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem with performance in this library for a specific use case, so I fixed it and sent a PR and it was accepted very quickly.
If this is causing you a particular problem it would be great if you could look into it and contribute back.
I agree with the previous very eloquent answer, this is a great library that meets the needs of many many people.